# Entity Framework 5 Code-First Many-to-Many Table Re-naming with inherited classes (TPC)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Ok I'm having some issues with Entity framework when trying to specify the name of the join tables as follows:

```
// Used by a bunch of things...
public abstract BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract ThingsBaseClass : BaseClass
{
    public virtual ICollection<Things> Things { get; set; }    
}

public First : ThingsBaseClass
{
    // This holds items of type First and doesn't have any other properties
}

public Second : ThingsBaseClass
{
    // This holds items of type Second and doesn't have any other properties
}

public Things
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Many to Many
    public virtual ICollection<First> Firsts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Second> Seconds { get; set; }
}
```

So everything works fine, except the tables are as follows:

```
First
FirstThings
Second
SecondThings
Things
```

I am trying to rename to:

```
First
Second
ThingFirsts
ThingSeconds
Things
```

Trying to rename them using the following code gives some very strange and random errors:

```
public class ThingConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Thing>
{
    HasMany(x => x.Firsts)
        .WithMany(x => x.Things)
         .Map(x => x.ToTable("ThingFirsts"));

    HasMany(x => x.Firsts)
        .WithMany(x => x.Things)
        .Map(x => x.ToTable("ThingSeconds"));    
}
```

I'm trying to use Code First Migrations to update the database (or just create it from scratch)

Errors include some of the following:

`Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(28,6) : error 0040: Type Thing_First is not defined in namespace Project.Domain.Repositories (Alias=Self).`

or

`Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(126,6) : error 0074: NavigationProperty 'Thing' is not valid. Type 'Project.Domain.Repositories.Second' of FromRole 'Thing_Firsts_Target' in AssociationType 'Project.Domain.Repositories.Thing_Second' must exactly match with the type 'Project.Domain.Repositories.First' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.`

If I get rid of the inheritance of First and Second and directly put in the `Id`, `Name` and `ICollection<Thing> Things` it works without issue.

There is no reason to use the inheritance other than I have about 5 of these objects that have nearly identical `BaseClass`es and wanted to keep it DRY.

Should I just bite the bullet and repeat the code everywhere to keep it simpler for Entity Framework?

Am I missing something simple? Any other "gotcha"s I'll run into with using inherited classes?

Does EF 6 have better support for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the attribute on the model class definition.

```
[TableName("WhateverYouWant")]
public class First{}
```

You might want to consider the "favor composition over inheritance" and treat the shared values as a property instead of a base class and use an interface to treat them polymorphically.  DRY is important but more so for behavior.  Two objects having the same properties shouldn't automatically cause a base class to spawn, two classes having the same behavior would be more likely to.  Inheritance and other object oriented methodologies are about normalizing behavior, not about normalizing data and properties.  After all 2 classes that implement the same interface would have duplicate property definitions; that's ok.

Comment: Doesn't that name the table, and not the join table? I've pretty much given up on this for now and just went to using non-inherited classes and ended up changing from Many-Many to two One-Many tables with my own join class. Just thought I had found a strange bug in Entity Framework since it wouldn't allow me to specify the name of both tables, just one of them (when using inheritance)